# How can I fix this unexpected token (JSON parser error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I am trying to save data from an API to my database, but I'm running into an error. The error states: `unexpected token at 'object' (JSON::ParserError)`

Here is my code:

```
require 'rest-client'
require 'pp'

endpoint = "https://api.leaddyno.com/v1/leads"

class TestDyno

  def parser(page_number)
    ## API key
    request = {:params => {:key => Rails.application.secrets.LEADDYNO_PRIVATE, page: page_number}}

    ## Parse JSON
    response = JSON.parse(RestClient.get endpoint, request)

    @response_count = response.count # Count results on the page.

    pp response

    puts response_count
  end


  def data
    until @response_count == 0
      1.upto(5) do |page_number|
        response['object'].each do |item|
          LeaddynoLead.save(
              leaddyno_lead_id: item['id'],
              email: item['email'],
              first_name: item['first_name'],
              last_name: item['last_name'],
              latest_visitor_id: item['latest_visitor']['id'],
              latest_visitor_code: item['latest_visitor']['tracking_code'],
              url: item['url']['url'],
              referrer_id: item['referrer']['id'],
              referrer_url: item['referrer']['url'],
              leaddyno_affiliate_id: item['affiliate']['id'],
              leaddyno_affiliate_email: item['affiliate']['email'],
              search_term: item['search_term']['term'],
              search_engine: item['search_term']['search_engine'],
              leaddyno_tracking_code: item['tracking_code'],
              created_at: item['created_at'],
              updated_at: item['updated_at']
              )
            sleep 0.5
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

retrieve = TestDyno.new
retrieve.data
```

I guess I need another set of eyes to look at this and see what is wrong?

The API docs are [here](http://developer.leaddyno.com/rest-api.html) if that helps. Thanks.

Comment: what do you intend doing with `JSON['object']` ??

Comment: `JSON.parse(RestClient.get endpoint, request)` this syntax may be  wrong. Try `JSON.parse RestClient.get(endpoint, request)`

Comment: @bjhaid Oh, wow! I guess I've been staring at this code for too long. Don't know how I missed that.

Comment: @Santhosh That part works, both ways. I still have the same problem however.

Comment: @NeyLive @Santhosh because ruby is right associative,not only are those both equivalent but you can leave out the parenthesis all together: `JSON.parse RestClient.get endpoint, request`

Comment: @NeyLive this line looks wierd: `JSON['object']` did you mean `response['object']`.

Comment: @maxpleaner Yes, I fixed that line. Now an undefined local variable issue but I can sort that out. Then I'll see if I still have the same problem.

Comment: @NeyLive glad to hear that. It's very helpful if yu include your error in the question, i.e. the stack trace